# Clear Firebase persistent storage on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How do I clear Firebase persistent storage on iOS ? Signing out doesn't clear it, setting cache size to 1kb breaks the app, setting persistent storage to no after fir.configure also breaks the app.

Comment: Yes, my android colleague does the force restart of the app on sign out, unfortunately that option is not available on iOS as far as my knowledge serves me.

Comment: Btw setting the persistant storage to false shouldn't break the app...

Comment: It does and it says that you should do all your configuration prior to fir.configure.